# latent representation of users and products for next basket recommendation

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am trying to use Neural Network for next basket recommendation according to http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1441/recsys2015_poster15.pdf. There is point about latent representations of users and products. So I would like to understand how to create them and train them. Should I use embedding layer?